# Rotation about an arbitrary axis

Tags: 3d, rotations

I'm dealing with rotation about an arbitrary axis and I know the vector of this axis and angle that I want to rotate. Is there a way to calculate angles of this rotation into a rotation about an XYZ axis.

Let's say I have axis with vector (1, 1, 1) and 30° angle, what would be angles for x, y and z rotation using [basic matrices for rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations), so I would get the same result.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the decomposition into Euler angles. The problem is that the result depends on which order you're planning to do the x-, y-, and z-rotations in.

Here's the drill, though:

Step 1: Convert your rotation to a $3 \times 3$ orthogonal matrix using Rodrigues' formula. This is well-detailed on Wikipedia and elsewhere, so I won't go into it here.

Step 2: Your matrix $M$ has three columns, $u_1, u_2, u_3$. Let's say you want to write 
$$
M = R_x R_y R_z
$$
where the $R$s are rotations (by varying amounts) around the three axes. We could then write
$$
R_y^{-1}R_x^{-1}M = R_z
$$
which, since a rotation about $z$ has interesting entries only in its upper left $2 \times 2$ block, means that we need
$$
R_y^{-1}R_x^{-1}u_3 = e_3
$$
where $e_3$ is the vector $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

Let's make that happen. First, we'll find an $x$-rotation that "kills off" the first entry of $u_3$.

Case 1: Both the first and last entries of $u_3$ are 0. In this case, perform no rotation about the $y$ axis, and if the second entry is 1, pick $R_x$ to rotate about $x$ by $90$ degrees; if the second entry is $-1$, pick $R_x$ to rotate about $x$ by $-90$ degrees. With these choices, $R_x^{-1}u_3$ will be $e_3$.

Case 2: At least one of these entries is nonzero. Let's call them $s$ and $c$. Let $\alpha = \text{atan2}(c, s)$, and let $R_y$ be rotation about $y$ by angle $\alpha$. Then $R_y^{-1} u_3$ will have its first entry zero, and its third entry nonzero. Call the second and third entries of $R_y^{-1} u_3$ by the names $a$ and $b$ respectively. Let $\beta = \text{atan2}(b, a)$, and let $R_x$ be rotation about $x$ by angle $\beta$. Then 
$$
R_x^{-1}R_y^{-1} u_3 = e_3.
$$
That means that 
$$
R_x^{-1}R_y^{-1} M = \begin{bmatrix}
c' & -s' & 0\\
s' & c' & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},
$$
and we can write $\gamma = \text{atan2}(c', s')$ and let $R_z$ be rotation about $z$ by angle $\gamma$, and we're done.

It's quite possible that I've made a sign error here somewhere: that one of the angles should be the negative of what I wrote. But if you write a program to implement this, it should be pretty obvious where any error is.

Comment: This could be problem. If I understand the Rodrigues' formula, I need to know the vector, which I want to rotate. I will be rotating big amount of vectors and obviously I don't want to do this process for every one of them when it's the same rotation. Or do I count the angles for one of them and just use it for the other vectors?

Comment: No, you don't. If the vector you're rotating around is $\mathbf{k} = (k_1, k_2, k_3)$, you build the matrix $K= \mathbf{K}=  
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -k_3 & k_2 \\
k_3 & 0 & -k_1 \\
-k_2 & k_1 & 0
\end{array}\right]$, and the construct $\mathbf{R} = \mathbf{I} + (\sin\theta) \mathbf{K} + (1-\cos\theta)\mathbf{K}^2$, and $\mathbf{R}$ is the rotation matrix you're looking for.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The most useful way to represent rotations in 3D is using quaternions. In such representation a rotation of an angle $2\theta$ in space, around an axis passing through the origin, is represented by a quaternion $e^{\mathbf{u}\theta}$, where $\mathbf{u}$ is the imaginary quaternion that correspond to the unit vector oriented along the axis of rotation.  So we have the correspondence:
$$
 \vec{w}=R_{\mathbf{u},\theta} \; \vec{v} \quad \longleftrightarrow \quad \mathbf{w}= e^{\mathbf{u}\theta/2}\mathbf{v}e^{-\mathbf{u}\theta/2}
$$

( see [Quaternions vs Axis angle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435680/quaternions-vs-axis-angle/1071145#1071145))

For example, given the rotation  around the axis passing through the origin and  the point of coordinates $(1,1,1)$ and angle $\theta=\pi/2$, it is easy to write the corresponding quaternion:
$$
e^{\frac{\theta}{4}\frac{ (\mathbf{i}+\mathbf{j}+\mathbf{k})}{\sqrt{3}}}
$$
If You don't know how calculate quaternion exponentials you can see my answer in [Exponential Function of Quaternion - Derivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030737/exponential-function-of-quaternion-derivation/1047246#1047246).

Comment: This is often correct...but not always. If you have computer hardware that likes x- y- and z-rotations, for instance (like the Evans and Sutherland PS300, to cite an ancient example), then expressing things as the OP asked may be a better choice. So perhaps you can explain to the OP how to factor an arbitrary unit quaternion $q$ into a product $q = q_x q_y q_z$ of three unit quaternions, the first of which has zeros in the $jk$ components, the second of which has zeros in the $ik$ components, and the third of which has zeros in the $ij$ components.

Comment: @ John: Your answer is a good explanation of the use of Euler angles. My answer was only a suggestion of another method. I'm not a programmer so I don't know what are the most used programs but, af far sa I know, quaternions are very useful in programming 3D rotations.