# Trigonometry : get cartesians extremities of a segment

Tags: trigonometry

To explain my situation, I am working with haptics devices connected with a stylus (a simple rod). I am calculating the middle of the stylus and its orientation according to a 3d frame (+y is right, +z is up and x is towards) in order to send thoses data to a robotic arm. Then I'd like to create a simple position controller to make the movement smoother, so I acquire the arm's end effector position/orientation that correspond to the middle of the stylus and send it back to the controller. As I need to control both haptics separately so I need to calculate both stylus extremities.
It is a trigonometric issue : I am looking to get cartesian positions of the stylus' extremities from orientation and middle position.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This might be better posed on Physics Stack Exchange or Engineering Stack Exchange (Beta).

Comment: I don't think so because it is trigonometry

Comment: Those other sites use math, but they may be more familiar with your instrument set up...This site may be able to help, I was only suggesting that this site may not be the most effective way to get your question answered.

Comment: all right, thank you for the suggestion, I'll post there too

Answer (score 0):

If the middle point is $(x_M,y_M,z_M)^T$  and th orientation versor is $(u_x,u_y,u_z)^T$, than the equation of the stright line for the stylus is:
$$
(x,y,z)^T=(x_M,y_M,z_M)^T+t(u_x,u_y,u_z)^T
$$

so, if the leght of the stylus is $l$, the extremities are:
$$
(x_M,y_M,z_M)^T\pm \dfrac{l}{2}(u_x,u_y,u_z)^T
$$

Comment: thanks emilio for this answer, but the problem is to evaluate the orientation vector. I am stuck with euler angles, I am not able to find ux depending on yaw, pitch or roll, any suggestion?

Comment: If your problem  is to find the orientation versor I think that is better if you post another question (with a different title) where you better specify what you know and what you find.   Maybe that your problem can be solved using quaternions. You can see here:                                                                       http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435680/quaternions-vs-axis-angle/1071145#1071145  and related questions.